# Django, querying data when we have table hierarchy

Tags: django, django-models, hierarchy

Let's consider that we have three tables in a **hierarchical** form:

```
Course 
    Topic 
        Sub-Topic
```

or in code:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Topic(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    course          = models.ForeignKey('Course' , null = True , blank = True)

class SubTopic(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    topic          = models.ForeignKey('Topic' , null = True , blank = True)
```

What I want is to get list of Courses, Topics and sub-topics to represent in a **tree like** Navigation system.

I know that `select_related()` can follow and discover `ForeignKeys` in any depth.  How can I get use of the feature in my scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to output to a template you can use [_set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) e.g. if you passed a list of courses to your template.

```
{% for c in courses %}
    {{c.name}}
    {% for t in c.topic_set.all %}
       {{t.name}}
       {% for st in t.subtopic_set.all %}
           {{st.name}}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: nice .. so I just have to fetch courses using `Course.objects.select_related()` or similar in the views and pass them to the template .. right ??

Comment: Course.objects.all() would do, select_related just gets the related FK data up front, rather then later when its accessed. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related